# Destroy Xml view sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an App not develloped in Sapui5 at all. But I loke the Grid Table and its option, therefore I integrate it into an Div dedicaced for it.

This is my Code:

```
 sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                    sap.ui.require([

                    ], function () {

                        new sap.ui.xmlview({
                            viewName : "sap.ui.demo.cart.view.DcpTable"
                        }).placeAt("vueAppSales");

                    })
                }
        );
```

I injected this div with Ajax.

When i leave  this page and i come back to this page, the same code was launched another time and the xmlview was duplicate.

How can i handle that to test if the element is create or not to duplicate the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give an id to your view and after that you can check if your view was created already or not

```
 sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                sap.ui.require([

                ], function () {
                    var myView = sap.ui.getCore().byId('myView')
                    if(!myView){
                      myView = new sap.ui.xmlview({
                          id: 'myView'
                          viewName : "sap.ui.demo.cart.view.DcpTable"
                      })
                    }
                    myView.placeAt("vueAppSales");
                })
            }
    );
```

but its only a guess